# Using jQuery slideup or slidedown effects to switch between asp views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, css

I have a few asp views that I would like to switch between with a slideup or slidedown jquery effect as opposed to the default choppy effect.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, toggle and (slideup and slidedown) have the same functionality imo.

what you could do is take your content, and wrap it in a div.

Pseudocode:

```
$(function(){
  $("div").hide();
  $("span").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

body:

```
<span>Click me</span>
<div>
  <asp:dropdownlist></asp:dropdownlist>
</div>
```

Comment: as a sidenote:  ASP controls can have a lot of weird stuff sometimes, so i like to wrap them to make things neat and tidy on the client side (from the programming perspective).

Comment: Thanks! How can I possibly embed this in my C# (.cs page) code as opposed to my html (.ascx page)?

Comment: That i do not know.  I actually put all my js in the html and not in the .cs page.  Wish i could be more help there.

Answer (score 1):

Best and simple way to achieve this would be: Create a single parent view with a parent div and load your child views dynamically on this with their content (tables, input elements etc).

To achieve the sliding effect on a div element, reference this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)